# Python Lambda Function Parsing DynamoDB's to JSON

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I develop a AWS Lambda in Python. I read data in dynamoDB but after I want return json data to APIGateway.

```
print(dynamodbTableQueryData)
#{'year': Decimal('2015'), 'info': {'rating': Decimal('0'), 'plot': 'Nothing happens at all.'}, 'title': 'The Big New Movie'}

 return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'body': json.dumps(dynamodbTableQueryData)
}
```

if I write this, the `title` is returned on APIGateway:

```
    return {
        ​'statusCode': 200,
        ​'body': json.dumps(dynamodbTableQueryData['title'])
   ​ }
```

if I write this, the `year` is not returned on APIGateway and I have an error:

```
    return {
        ​'statusCode': 200,
        ​'body': json.dumps(dynamodbTableQueryData['year'])
   ​ }
```

this error:

```
[ERROR] TypeError: Object of type Decimal is not JSON serializable Traceback (most recent call last)
```

I try this but do not work:

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.types import TypeSerializer, TypeDeserializer
ts= TypeSerializer()
td = TypeDeserializer()

deserialized_data= td.deserialize(dynamodbTableQueryData)
print(deserialized_data)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because JSON object must only contain specific types such as list, dict, str, int, float, etc. Thus for the types that are not supported such as `Decimal`, `datetime`, etc., we should explicitly define how should they be parsed by defining a custom serializer. For example, should `Decimal('2015')` be a string `"Decimal(2015)"` or just the number part `"2015"` or should it be an int `2015` or float `2015.0` or something else.

Here is a solution that also works recursively if the `Decimal` object is in an inner nest. We will get the string value of the number e.g. `"2015"` (I chose str type because returning float might be inconsistent depending on the tech stack e.g. `1.2` might be interpreted as `1.20000001`). This will be implemented via the `default` and `cls` argument to [json.dumps()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) which as documented:

> If specified, ***default*** should be a function that gets called for objects that can’t otherwise be serialized. It should return a JSON encodable version of the object or raise a TypeError. If not specified, TypeError is raised.

```
from decimal import Decimal
import json

dynamodbTableQueryData = {'year': Decimal('2015'), 'info': {'rating': Decimal('0'), 'plot': 'Nothing happens at all.'}, 'title': 'The Big New Movie'}

# Solution 1
def to_serializable(val):
    if isinstance(val, Decimal):
        return str(val)
    return val

print("Solution 1")
result = json.dumps(dynamodbTableQueryData['info'], default=to_serializable)
print(result)
result = json.dumps(dynamodbTableQueryData['title'], default=to_serializable)
print(result)
result = json.dumps(dynamodbTableQueryData['year'], default=to_serializable)
print(result)

# Solution 2

class MyJSONEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            return str(obj)
        else:
            return super().default(obj)

print("Solution 2")
result = json.dumps(dynamodbTableQueryData['info'], cls=MyJSONEncoder)
print(result)
result = json.dumps(dynamodbTableQueryData['title'], cls=MyJSONEncoder)
print(result)
result = json.dumps(dynamodbTableQueryData['year'], cls=MyJSONEncoder)
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
Solution 1
{"rating": "0", "plot": "Nothing happens at all."}
"The Big New Movie"
"2015"
Solution 2
{"rating": "0", "plot": "Nothing happens at all."}
"The Big New Movie"
"2015"
```